# Thingiview and Three.js script conflict

Tags: javascript, three.js, conflict

I have a problem with Three.js and Thingiview.js (that come from Three.js).
I have a conflict with those two libraries/scripts. (I think the three.js and three.min.js files).
Here I can only have 50% of my scripts :s

What I want to do is showing my scene with thingiview and calculate the boundingbox with three.js.

I hope you know a solution for this kind of conflict. I have passed all the day on it :(

Here is the code that I call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
<script src="thingview/javascripts/Three.js"></script>
<script src="thingview/javascripts/thingiview.js"></script>
<script>
  var modele = document.getElementById('modele3d').value; 

    window.onload = function() {
      // You may want to place these lines inside an onload handler
      CFInstall.check({
        mode: "inline", // the default
        node: "prompt"
      });

      thingiurlbase = "";
      thingiview = new Thingiview("viewer");
      thingiview.setObjectColor('#e4e5e6');
      thingiview.initScene();
      thingiview.loadSTL('../../images/'+modele);
      log(thingiview.objectColor);
    }

</script>
<div id="viewer" style="width:400px;height:300px;margin:auto;position:relative;border:5px solid white;border-radius:5px;"></div>




<script src="scripts/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="three/js/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="three/js/Detector.js"></script>
<script>
   var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
          var geometry = event.content;
          var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xd0d1d2, shininess: 5 } );
          var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material );   
          // Recherche et envoi des tailles //
          geometry.computeBoundingBox();
          var largeur = (mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.x)- (mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.x);
          var hauteur = (mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.y)-(mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.y);
          var profondeur = (mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.z)-(mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.z);

          var tailles = largeur + " " + hauteur + " " + profondeur;

          var prix  = document.getElementById('prototype_prix').value;
          if(prix==0){
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille1').value = (Math.round(largeur*100))/100;
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille2').value = (Math.round(hauteur*100))/100;
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille3').value = (Math.round(profondeur*100))/100;
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille1_base').value = largeur;  
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille2_base').value = hauteur;
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille3_base').value = profondeur; 
          }     

        } );
        loader.load( 'images/'+modele);
</script>
```

Comment: From what I see Thingiview.js is very old; two years or more. Three.js is still very active and can load STL and OBJ models. The second part of your code does load STL files without Thingiview. So I dont see the problem.

Comment: Thingiview can also load STL (it has been made for it). But it seems that thingiview use also à old version of three.js and this old version enter in conflict with the new.

Comment: I agree with gaitat. Thingiview seems to be very old and unmaintained. Unless Thingiview author decides to update it for newer Three.js versions, there is not much sense to continue using it. I don't think there is much in Thingiview that you couldn't do easily with only Three.js and a little bit of code.

Comment: The problem is that I have try a showing system with three.js but I'm not good enough to build a good one (for the moment it's showing some file perfectely and some other file without shadow). It's for this that I have choosed thingiview (it's very easy and enough powerfull for me).

Comment: Yes three.js has a learning curve but in the end you would be glad you learned it. Take a look at the examples webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html and webgl_loader_stl.html to get started.

Comment: You're right, It's the best way to have exactely what I want and also good for after. Thank you guys!